# Removing a directory with files inside AppData

Tags: c#

Well, what I want to do is to remove my folder that is located inside Roaming. I want this to work for every user, so the username of every PC is different. I already know that to get path of AppData I need following:

```
var path = Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData;
```

But what to do to remove the folder with a specific name (Let's call it ExampleDir)? I tried this:

```
Path.Combine(path + "Kappa");
Directory.Delete(true.ToString());
```

But this does not work. I am beginner at C#, still, I want to practice. Will be grateful for help =)

Comment: So did you find what you were looking for, or...?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `Path.Combine()` is used to replace string concatenation so don't concatenate strings in it. Pass every name you want to concatenate as a parameter and the function will do the rest.

Secondly, to remove a folder containing files you have to use the `Directory.Delete(string, bool)` overload. The `bool` value (called `recursive`) indicates wether you want to remove files and subfolders in the specified directory **(see the [MSDN Documentation for Directory.Delete()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f(v=vs.110).aspx))**.

And finally, `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` is just an enumration (meaning it's just a number). You have to pass it as a parameter to the `Environment.GetFolderPath()` method to get the actual path of the AppData folder.

Example:

```
string AppDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string FolderToDelete = Path.Combine(AppDataFolder, "Kappa");

try
{
    Directory.Delete(FolderToDelete, true); //Setting "recursive" to true will remove every subfile/-folder.
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //An error occurred, use this block to log it/show it to the user/whatever.
    //ex.Message - The error message.
    //ex.StackTrace - Where in the code the error occurred.
}
```

**EDIT:**

As @dman2306 said in his comment, some exception handling is good practice in case of that the deletion fails. I have added this to my above code.

The code in the `try` block will run until an exception is thrown (if any). If an exception is thrown the execution will move on to the `catch` block, which is where you catch the exception and perform for example error logging, stopping other procedures, etc.

**EDIT 2:**

<s>You *possibly* have to add "Roaming" to `Path.Combine()`. I am unsure if it's already included or not, and I'm unable to test that now.</s>

```
string FolderToDelete = Path.Combine(AppDataFolder, "Roaming", "Kappa");
```

**Forget what I said**, `SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` gives you the path to the `Roaming` folder.

Comment: The OP should probably include a try/catch for `Directory.Delete` as it will fail in situations like the directory doesn't exist, there is a read only file, files are in use, etc.

Comment: @dman2306 : Also, a more thorough example to why `Path.Combine()` is better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17098724/3740093

Answer (score 0):

- First of all you are using `Path.Combine()` wrong. But you don't need that at all.
- Second you have to use backslases to separate folders in a path when combining them with +.
- And third: The method `Directory.Delete()` wants the path of the folder you want to delete as an argument.

Try this:

```
Directory.Delete(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData + "\\Kappa");
```

Comment: `Path.Combine()` is **WAY** better to use than normal string concatenation! So it's not a `you don't need that at all` thing.

Comment: OK I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Also, `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` is just an enumration, a number. You must use `Environment.GetFolderPath()` to get the AppData folder's path. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent While I agree `Path.Combine` is a good idea to use as it's cleaner and does some error handling, in this specific case, why is it "**WAY**" better? Given the use, other than code readability (which is certainly important) I'm not sure I see a benefit.

Comment: @dman2306 : Okay in this situation perhaps it's not "**WAY**" better, but overall it is a much better solution. It will make sure to concatenate the path correctly and it throws an exception if the path contains invalid characters, etc. It will build up a correct path following the standards/rules of a file/directory path. You can lookup exactly what it does via the [Microsoft Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,65c63f5b94b2ac9b).

Comment: @RomCoo : `somehow my code did work too.` - Are you really sure? What do you get if you put your `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData + "\\Kappa"` line in a MessageBox? Because I highly doubt it's the path to the AppData folder. **See the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx).**

Comment: @VisualVincent So my understanding is: using Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData alone won't work, but putting Environment.GetFolderPath() behind it will actually make it like normal path I normally use (in this case it's just like "%AppData%/Roaming/Kappa"). Do I understand this correctly :P?

Comment: @Monnq : Yes, but the absolute path (like `C:\Users\Vincent\AppData`). I've covered everything in my answer.